# Short- or long-form adjective?

Tags: грамматика, выбор-слова, прилагательные

At first I thought short-form adjectives were quite easy after seeing how they are formed. But when to use them turned out to be more complex. Here I have 5 sentences that made me confuse since they are all similar in terms of structure:

> Александр очень ленив.
>
> Маша очень общительная.
>
> Моя бабушка очень добрая.
>
> Он очень глуп.
>
> Итальянки очень красивы.

How do I decide which form to use when?

Comment: Traditionally, the long (full) forms mean a permanent feature/state, short forms mean a temporary, short-time feature/state. But most people use both forms indiscriminately. Also, some adjectives in the full form mean something completely different than in the short form. The rule of thumb for a beginner-level learner of Russian is _**always** use the **full** form_, with the course of time you'll learn when short forms are also possible. The short-form adjectives is a thing that's dying out in Russian right now.

Comment: Short/long forms are interchangeable only then the adjective is a predicate (or postpositive adjective, as in all of your examples), but never interchangeable as prepositive adjective (always use long form). "Ленивый Александр" is quite different from "Ленив Александр".

Comment: @YellowSky, you should have posted it as an answer. Steve, at least in your five examples, you can certainly use either way.

Answer (score 2):

All your examples can use short and long forms alike.

Short and long forms do have some very finely different stylistic shades: statements with short forms sound a little bit more certain and categorical. But it's not perceptible in isolation, outside of a larger context.

You should use short forms for:

- Adjectives whose meanings have split for the short and long forms: *малый, великий, живой* etc: *свитер мал; штаны велики; ребёнок жив*
- Past passive participles: *я польщён, она влюблена* etc.

Comment: _All your examples can use short and long forms alike._ With one exception: _X добрая_ and _X добра ко мне_ are perfect, but on reverse _X добра_ and _X добрая ко мне_ are quite off.

Comment: @DK: your phrases are not mentioned in op's examples. Of course you can only use the short form with adjuncts, but I was writing specifically about bare subject + predicate sentences