# вовлечённых - proper use in a translated English sentence for "involved"?

Tags: глаголы, падежи, participle

I had earlier asked a question about adjectives and participles, and cited this link:

[How to tell a participle from an adjective?](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/8001/how-to-tell-a-participle-from-an-adjective)

I now understand the answer of the above link better -

> The answers in the link above mention a distinction by either time,
>
> > A participle is a form of a verb that describes change over time. An
> >     adjective describes a more permanent attribute.
>
> or.... 'manifestation of change',
>
> > As far as I know, the participles mean "the ones which are being
> >     changed", and the adjectives mean "the ones that can
> >     be changed"
>
> though the latter person qualifies this only for the specific examples
>   in that link.

---

But **now I want to express** this second English sentence (first one is included only for context);

```
(There was a lot of paperwork to do.) 
Therefore our father wanted us involved in the meeting with the agent.
```

and I originally (now knowing to use a participle [plural, accusative, pass, passive, perfective]) suggested the second sentence as;

```
(Нам ну́жно бы́ло заполнить мно́го докуме́нтов.)
Поэ́тому наш оте́ц хоте́л нас вовлечённых в встре́чу с агентом.
```

---

Aside from this second sentence sounding formal, or awkward, is it grammatically correct?

Did I use the proper case/gender/number? ("us" is a male & a female)

I am especially interested in the case of the participle, as applying cases to participles is something I am having great difficulty with. (I assume that, since который can be substituted for a present active participle, that the case of a participle is governed in the same manner as it is for который)

If not a good word, is there an alterantive participle in the same/a different case to use?

Comment: _Привлечь (нас) к участию_ or _задействовать (нас)_ might give you some more flexibility here if you desire to stick closer to English phrasing. Quassnoi answer is great: it's not easy to be _вовлечённым_ in a meeting without making it sound really awkward, though it's totally OK to be _вовлечённым в оформление документов_ or (colloquially) _вовлечённым в "бумажную работу"_, e.g. _Отец хотел вовлечь нас в эту бумажную работу и чтобы мы присутствовали при/на встрече с агентом._

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your sentence is not grammatically correct.

You cannot just calque *wanted us involved* into Russian, it does not work this way.

Correct literal translation, albeit a stylistically sloppy one, would be *поэтому наш отец и хотел, чтобы мы были вовлечены во встречу с агентом*.

In the sentences which do work like this, you have to put the participle in instrumental:

> - Ей никак не хотелось признать себя побеждённой. // She didn't want to admit being defeated (literally "admit herself defeated")
> - Здесь трудовой человек не может чувствовать себя заброшенным и одиноким // Here a working person cannot feel abandoned and alone (literally, "cannot feel oneself abandoned")
> - Я хотел было войти в калитку, но, против обыкновения, нашёл её запертой // I was about to go in at the gate, but found that, contrary to the common usage, it was locked (literally, "found it locked")

Comment: The examples are appreciated!

Comment: These examples, with cases, distracted me from wondering why you still elected to use the very same participle I did, just the "short-form". Books just tell me that the long-forms are "bookish" (maybe related to what @DK. said above in comment) and can be interchanged w/ который+<past tense быть>+<short form>. The only other difference I see in long vs short is wrt adjectives (and, at least active participles) whereby short-forms can be used both predicatively and attributively. How can you use the short-form but not the long-form?

Comment: you can only use the short form with the past passive participles in predicative role. In *я был молодой / я был молод* both options are ok (it's an adjective), in _я был вовлечён / * я был вовлечённый_ only the first one is (it's a participle). This is something I mentioned here https://russian.stackexchange.com/a/22548/134

Comment: Okay, it's a rule - "you can only use the short form with the past passive participles in predicative role" that I apparently did not come across. I will write this down, as it is contrary to the use of the short adjective. Thanks!